# Cannot get an R.java file to generate after importing AppCompat v7 into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file, android-appcompat

I have been grinding at this for hours on end. I seem to do everything right according to google and other answers to this same question, yet I still get no R.java file in my project. I appear to not have any errors in any of my resources.

[image: My Porject's file view]
[image: appcompat five view]

as soon as I remove the library reference in my project, the R file is generated again. The errors in the project are simply due to the lack of an R.java file.

Comment: menu project > clean

Comment: dont just clean restart eclipse

Comment: I have cleaned and restarted eclipse a handfull of times. nothing

Comment: Sometimes if your layout contains errors, the R file is not generated correctly. Make sure all layout files in res folder are error free

Comment: when I undo the library reference, the R file comes back. So my layouts are fine

Comment: when you add the support v7 than you have to add appropriate resources too like style attr etc just putting the v7 jar is not the way to using support v7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by updating my build-tools...........

Answer (score 0):

Please check the console section. Sometimes there is a JAR mismatch. The JAR in the library may have a different size or signature compared to the one in your project. You may have to replace the JAR files to have a consistent copy or Delete one of them.

Comment: Nothing. That is not the issue (at least it doesn't say it is)