# R.java is not generating due to appcompat v7?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file, android-appcompat

I am using Eclipse, I added the appcompat lib to my project ands suddenly the R.java file is not generating.
But in my Console it is showing like this whenever i clean the project.

```
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:178: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:182: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:113: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:115: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:110: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:107: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:121: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:126: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:138: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:143: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:129: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:132: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:146: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:150: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:154: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:158: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:164: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:168: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:172: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:174: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:97: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:101: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:62: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:42: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:50: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:52: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:54: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] 
[2014-11-02 18:50:16 - Client] G:\ProgramZ\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
```

This is my File structure

I tried to migrate this project to android studio. The Gradle file is also not generating due to this Error. So please Suggest a good way to overcome this ...
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Seems like you haven't set the `target` properly in the `appcompat-v7` project.properties. Read more about it in this [StackO-Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro/26449172#26449172)

Comment: @reVerse i have already saw that post & Tried Everything.

Comment: Can you check if 1) your appcompat project is a library project 2)it does not have errors, i.e. appcompat/bin contains expected jar files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18563441/after-setting-up-android-support-v7-appcompat-r-java-is-missing), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496984/cannot-get-an-r-java-file-to-generate-after-importing-appcompat-v7-into-eclipse), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124153/android-issues-with-r-after-importing-v7-appcompat)

Comment: @ArulNadhan did you find a solution ? I'm facing the same prob

Answer (score 5):

Change your appcompat build target to Android 5.0

Then your project too.. then rebuild it

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem , if u made any updates and deleted previous SDK Build Tools then the reason is targeting wrong version of android.
If u change the target it will run or re-install those deleted SDK Build tools it will solve the problem too.
This is the same problem i used to get when i first started android .
:) All the best

Answer (score 0):

I has same issue. After updating to the latest *SDK Tools*, *SDK Platform-tools* and *SDK Build-tools* everything compiles again. Make sure you have latest versions installed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hey friend carefully read your error log v21 it means version 21 has some problem if you dont updated sdk please update your sdk and set target Android 5.0 and don't worry your app will work on down version till min sdk you provided you just have to change the target sdk as per error log.

Thanks